# CSS: Problem in IE7 with a floating element. Clearing it doesn't work

Tags: css, css-float

I have this [page](http://tirengarfio.com).

The register form should be on the right on the sign in form, but it doesn't...

I added "clear:right" to the registering div, but it doesn't work..

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you shouldn't use tables to mark up forms like that. Use <label> and CSS instead!

Comment: I don't think using label and css is better in this case, because then it would be very difficult to ensure that the input boxex are horizontal allignet. (Or did I miss a solution not using nested tags with display:block; ?

Comment: Regardless, this is an incorrect use of tables. Simply nesting the <input> elements in <label>s, floating them and setting the correct overflow or height on <label> will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase width of `div#contenedor_formularios`.

Comment: I gave more left margin to registering div but it doesn't work. Maybe I don't understand you..

Comment: You're right, i modified my answer. I've tested this one, so it should work.